# Different interfaces in Typescript Factory

Tags: node.js, express, design-patterns, nestjs, factory

I have a factory like that:

```
@Injectable()
export class JobApiFactoryService
  implements ApiServiceFactoryInterface<JobApiPayloads>
{
  public constructor(
    private readonly createApplicationActivityService: CreateApplicationActivityService,
    private readonly createActivityService: CreateActivityService
  ) {}

  public async execute(
    payload: JobApiPayloads,
    action: ApiNamesEnum
  ): Promise<void> {
    switch (action) {
      case ApiNamesEnum.CREATE_JOB_APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_EXTENSION:
        await this.createApplicationActivityService.execute(payload);
        break;
      case ApiNamesEnum.CREATE_JOB_ACTIVITY:
        await this.createActivityService.execute(payload);
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error("Invalid action");
    }
  }
}
```

JobApiPayloads:

```
   export type JobApiPayloads = JobApplicationActivityExtensionPayloadInterface |
  JobActivityExtensionInterface;
```

**createApplicationActivityService** it's using **JobApplicationActivityExtensionPayloadInterface** as type for payload

**createActivityService** it's using **JobActivityExtensionInterface** as type for payload

I get this error:

> Argument of type 'JobApiPayloads' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JobApplicationActivityExtensionPayloadInterface'.   Type 'JobActivityExtensionInterface' is missing the following properties from type 'JobApplicationActivityExtensionPayloadInterface': jobId, candidate_ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the payload type:

```
async execute(payload: JobApiPayloads, action: ApiNamesEnum): Promise<void> {
  switch (action) {
    case ApiNamesEnum.CREATE_JOB_APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_EXTENSION:
      await this.createApplicationActivityService.execute(<JobApplicationActivityExtensionPayloadInterface>payload);
      break;
    case ApiNamesEnum.CREATE_JOB_ACTIVITY:
      await this.createActivityService.execute(<JobActivityExtensionInterface>payload);
      break;
  }
}
```

Or you can refactor the models to take advantage of the automatic type inference:

```
class CreateApplicationActivityAction {
  type = ApiNamesEnum.CREATE_JOB_APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_EXTENSION;
  constructor(public readonly payload: JobApplicationActivityExtensionPayloadInterface) {}
}

class CreateJobActivityAction {
  type = ApiNamesEnum.CREATE_JOB_ACTIVITY;
  constructor(public readonly payload: JobActivityExtensionInterface) {}
}

type JobApiAction = CreateApplicationActivityAction | CreateJobActivityAction;

/* ... */

async execute(action: JobApiAction): Promise<void> {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ApiNamesEnum.CREATE_JOB_APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_EXTENSION:
      // no cast is necessary because the compiler has inferred
      // the type of `action.payload` to be `JobApplicationActivityExtensionPayloadInterface`
      await this.createApplicationActivityService.execute(action.payload);
      break;
    case ApiNamesEnum.CREATE_JOB_ACTIVITY:
      await this.createActivityService.execute(action.payload);
      break;
  }
}

/* ... */

this.jobApiFactoryService.execute(new CreateJobActivityAction(payload));
```

By the way that's not a factory, it doesn't produce anything.